# Rails autoloading behaves strangely in RSpec with modules and subclasses with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

In my Rails app I've added the following files:
app/models/baz.rb
lib/presenters/foo_presenter.rb
lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar.rb
spec/models/baz_spec.rb
spec/lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar_spec.rb

The contents of lib/presenters/foo_presenter.rb is something like:

```rb
module Presenters
  module FooPresenter
    def self.render
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

The contents of lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar.rb is like:

```rb
module Presenters
  class FooPresenter::Bar
    def baz
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

The contents of spec/lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar_spec.rb is like:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

module Presenters::FooPresenter
  describe Bar do
    # some tests
  end
end
```

Then I have a spec file in spec/models/baz_spec.rb:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Baz do
  it 'works' do
    Presenters::FooPresenter.render
  end
end
```

(The contents of app/models/baz.rb is not relevant to this issue)
The problem is when I run `rspec spec/models/baz_spec.rb` it works fine without spork, but when spork is running, I get an error like:
NameError: undefined method `render' for Presenters::FooPresenter:Module

I traced through the code a bit and noticed that when rspec loads spec/lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar_spec.rb it causes Rails to autoload lib/presenters/foo_presenter/bar.rb and so at that point Presenters::FooPresenter::Bar is loaded, but then when baz_spec.rb runs, lib/presenters/foo_presenter.rb has never been loaded and thus the exception. But this only happens if spork is running. The quick fix was to `require 'foo_presenter'` in a file in config/initializers, but is there a cleaner solution that doesn't need the explicit require? My guess is the issue here is that Rails doesn't autoload lib/presenters/foo_presenter.rb because Presenters::FooPresenter has already been defined by bar_spec.rb.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker and I were faced with this problem today and we eventually found we needed Spork to reload the classes on every run.  We used the each_run() method to do this:

```
Spork.each_run do
  Dir[Rails.root.join("app/classes/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```